# Name spaces Could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a project which should connect the Yahoo Weather API with ASP.Net MVC 3
After I have created the variables it has given me the error called "The type or namespace name 'WeatherForecast' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\kumi.SH\Documents\Learn\ASP.Net_MVC3\WeatherApp\WeatherApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs"

I have the following code in my HomeController.cs file:

```
public ActionResult GetWeather(string Id)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    WeatherForecast wf = new WeatherForecast();
    WeatherForecasts wfs = wf.GetWeatherByPlaceName(Id);
    WeatherData[] wd = wfs.Details;
    sb.AppendFormat("<B>Weather Forecast for {0}</B><br /><br />", wfs.PlaceName);
    foreach (WeatherData d in wd)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.WeatherImage))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<img src=\"{0}\" >", d.WeatherImage);
            sb.AppendFormat(" {0}", d.Day);
            sb.AppendFormat(", High {0}F", d.MaxTemperatureF);
            sb.AppendFormat(", Low {0}F<br />", d.MinTemperatureF);
        }
    }
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    return null;
}
```

Can you please specify the namespaces which needs to use?

Thankx in advance......

Comment: maybe you can find more information here http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/#howto

Comment: Is there from some one elses sample code? You're missing a using statment to tell the code where "WeatherForecast" is or your missnig the class files/assembly for it.

Comment: Looks like this code is from taken from this codeproject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Yes Robbie I was trying to do exactly the same thing but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your application uses the following web service?

http://www.webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx

If so, you will need to add a Service Reference to this service within the same project that you are trying to use it. I.e. the same project where the code in your example lives. Judging from the path in your example, that project is called "WeatherApp".

You can do this by right clicking on the project node in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add Service Reference". Then in the dialog that appears paste the service url (above) into the address bar and hit "Go" - Give it a name and then click "Ok"

[image: Add Service Reference Image]

Comment: Your idea was useful but it did not do anything for the error. Thank you and if you have any idea please send me

Comment: @Kumu after you have added the webservice reference, make sure that you have a using statement just above the class declaration that points to the web service. For example, if the namespace for the service reference was "WeatherService" you would need a using statement like this: `using WeatherService;` Alternatively, you could fully qualify the method call like this `new WeatherService.WeatherForecast();`

Comment: I couldn't even add the namespace reference like above you mentioned

Comment: @Kumu i think there were some issues with the web service yesterday as i was having problems with it timing out as well. Try it again today. Also, the CodeProject article your code sample comes from is pretty old, and hence the example it gives adds a web reference (using the old method) - you can try this by clicking on the "Advanced" button (from my screenshot above) and then selecting "Add Web Reference" (button) - try adding the reference like that and see if that fixes it. If you have already added the reference in the way i describe above, delete it before doing this. I hope this helps

Comment: http://www.webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx
link was working fine yesterday, but today it says the service is unavailable, can you please send me the alternative.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to use the Yahoo Weather API instead of using the webservicex.net? I have used the same example, but the service is not available.

Comment: @Xeoni (have you changed your name?) - sorry, i've never used the Yahoo Weather API so i'm not sure i would be best to explain it to you. I would suggest you start another question about it as it seems to be a different issue to this specific one. (also, i hit the webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx service this morning and it seems ok - it wasn't responding yesterday though, so i'm not sure if it's a reliable service)